# Why the exception is raised on the bank-side http request to my heroku resource with ssl certificate by Let's encrypt

Tags: java, ssl, heroku, keystore, lets-encrypt

What's wrong with ssl certificate for https://platforma.openshkola.ru ? It is not self-signed, but... The logs from the bank-side java service attached on their callback call to my resource.

```
2019-11-07 18:02:57,096 [callback-3] ERROR r.b.p.c.c.CallbackExecutor:49 - Error while sending first callback CallbackTO{merchantId=1579515003, merchantName='mentalplatform', url='https://platforma.openshkola.ru/letthespecificapibethesecret', params='{orderNumber=XXX, mdOrder=XXX, operation=deposited, status=1}', method='GET', successfulCode=null, successfulResponse='null', customQueueName='null'} javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error

at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)

at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)

at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2020)

at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1127)

at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)

at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)

at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)

at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)

at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.upgrade(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:185)

at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.upgrade(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:369)

at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:415)

at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)

at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)

at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)

at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)

at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)

at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)

at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)

at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)

at ru.bpc.payment.core.callback.HttpCallbackSender.send(HttpCallbackSender.java:96)

at ru.bpc.payment.core.callback.CallbackExecutor.lambda$0(CallbackExecutor.java:46)

at ru.bpc.payment.service.callback.PaymentCallbackService.lambda$1(PaymentCallbackService.java:97)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

the curl output there is:

```
curl -kvI https://platforma.openshkola.ru
* About to connect() to platforma.openshkola.ru port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 52.210.255.158...
* Connected to platforma.openshkola.ru (52.210.255.158) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=platforma.openshkola.ru
*   start date: Oct 10 20:35:30 2019 GMT
*   expire date: Jan 08 20:35:30 2020 GMT
*   common name: platforma.openshkola.ru
*   issuer: CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: platforma.openshkola.ru
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Cowboy
Server: Cowboy
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< Expires: 0
Expires: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
< Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com data:; frame-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com data:; frame-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com
< Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2019 11:26:38 GMT
Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2019 11:26:38 GMT
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
< Content-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Last-Modified: Thu, 07 Nov 2019 13:11:45 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 07 Nov 2019 13:11:45 GMT
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Feature-Policy: geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; speaker 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; payment 'none'
Feature-Policy: geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; speaker 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; payment 'none'
< Content-Length: 6260
Content-Length: 6260
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Via: 1.1 vegur
Via: 1.1 vegur

< 
* Connection #0 to host platforma.openshkola.ru left intact
```

Comment: What version of Java are you running on Heroku?

Comment: @codefinger I run 1.8, but it doesn't matter. The logs attached are not from my code, that is the external service, that calls for my app. And the technical support for it is able to send me logs only, which clarify nothing. So the side to fix something if possible is to adjust certificate of the website on the heroku side, but I''d like to understand what is wrong.

Comment: I think it's likely they are running on an old JDK that doesn't have Let's Encrypt root CA by default

Comment: @codefinger what is the convenient way to resolve issues like that? is it fixable with updating JDK to the later versions, or what? so what is a way to fix this things with missing roots?

Comment: OpenJDK added let's encrypt by default in 8u191 i believe. Otherwise they'll need to add the cert https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/tutorial-java-keystores-jks-with-lets-encrypt/34754

Comment: @codefinger you was right and that was the only explanation. Could you please post your comment as the only official answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The exception was because of older than having Let's Encrypt root CA version of jdk was running on the bank's side.

The approach to fix it on heroku is to provide for the banls' callback https url "youapplication.appspot.com", which deals not with Let's Encrypt but other certificate provider, not the obtained firs level domain hostname where only Let's Encrypt is available.